# Problem with voltage divider

Tags: voltage-divider

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUiIki.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a problem with a voltage divider circuit. I'm not an electrical engineer, so I am having some trouble finding a solution.
I have a circuit with ACS712 30A and another with a precision amplifier (INA125p) and both work properly. The problem is that both circuits give me an analog signal of max 5V. I have a microcontroller (msp432) that accepts an analog signal of max 3.3V. To solve this problem I have done another circuit that implements two voltage dividers. The problem is that when I link the voltage divider circuit, neither of the analog signals have the expected value.
In particular when I use the ACS712 circuit, and nothing is attached at the circuit, I measure a voltage of 2.48V, but when I attach the voltage divider circuit, at the same condition, I expect to read a voltage of 1.6V, but in reality I read a voltage of 0.6V.
Can someone help me find where I'm wrong?

Comment: Show us your schematic.

Comment: We have no idea what you are doing, how do you expect us to figure out where you did something wrong?

Comment: @brhans at this moment i haven't a schematic for my circuits, however i used a basic circuit that are in the datasheet of acs712 and ina125p

Comment: Use the built in schematic editor to make a schematic of what you have.

Comment: Give a schematic before this question is dumped.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, i'm sorry for this, but i have written my problem, in synthesis my problem is why when i link a voltage divider with another circuit, the voltage divider doen't work?

Comment: @SolveEtCoagula07, ok, I try to use a schematic editor, thank

Comment: Yep, need a schematic. My crystal ball is on the fritz.

Comment: If you'd done exactly what the datasheet(s) show then the likelihood of you having problems is almost zero. So there must be something wrong with what you've done. But you haven't shown us what you've actually done, and there are possibly many different ways of interpreting what you've described. A schematic of what you've done is unambiguous.

Comment: What happens when you make a 5V to 3.3V potential divider using a 1 ohm resistor and a 2 ohm resistor and attach it to a sensor?

Comment: @Luca80 Your ACS712 requires a load \$ge 4.7\:\text{k}\Omega\$. I don't know what load your INPA125P requires, but let's assume it's not less but probably more. It's also the case that the MSP432 ADC will require (I didn't look) a source lower than some value, too. To design a resistor divider, you are trapped between the output requirements on one side and the input requirements on the other. There may be a solution and there may not be. That's why so much attention is about not just the ICs, but the circuits surrounding them. It's important for considering a resistor divider.

Comment: @Luca80 see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common problem with voltage dividers when you feed the value into something which does not have a high enough resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhnvso.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you see in the above circuit, without the load the divider gives you half the applied voltage. With the load in parallel with the bottom resistor, you get 1/3 the voltage.

You can significantly reduce the resistances you use for the divider so they are much smaller than the load resistance to reduce this effect, or you can buffer the voltage with a voltage follower circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiexOg.png)</sup>

**UPDATE:**

Now you have added a schematic it is apparent your problem is your resistors are far too small. \$232\Omega\$ will draw over \$20mA\$ from 5V, but your IC can only deliver 10mA. As such your divider is pulling down the output.

Use something like 82K and 150K resistors.

Comment: I understand what you tell me! Now i try to do the same thing using another resistor values. Thank you so much Trevor_G! ;)

Comment: PS, at this moment i haven't a 82K and 150K resistor, i only have a 4.7K and 10K resistor. Using this value i obtain a resistor divider with the output value of about 3.4V. Also using your math, and my new resistor value the current is about of 0.3401 mA. I think that this configuration will work, however now i try this, stay tune for my update! ;)

Comment: Using the 4.7K and 10K resistors, the resistor divider work, but only for the ACS712. For the INA125P this setup is wrong. However tomorrow I change the external resistor so that I get the maximum output value near at 3.3V and the problem disapear!  In any case, again thank you so much Mr Trevor_G, the your answer solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

The voltage follower is a good start to resolving this issue.  But in order to get values that cross 0V (or even just approach it), you'll need a dual supply (+12V, -12V) for the op amp voltage follower.  If you don't use a dual supply, you'll get an offset voltage, just enough to throw off your expected output by around .6V to 1V

After this op amp, you'll need a second op amp to scale and balance the output in order to prepare it for the next stage.  Generally, there will be four equal resistors in a non-inverting adder configuration, and an offset voltage.

After this, you scale again (a second voltage divider) with the input load impedance included (from the next stage) calculated into your circuit.  You can find this on the data sheet, where it shows the input resistance/impedance.

Finally, you can model every bit of this in LTSpice before you build it.